# What exactly it mean by "Data Type of a Column Name" in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am learning Cassandra. I came across [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/use_comparator_c.html) Datastax doc page.
This page explains about Column comparators and I stuck on a statement, it says

```
Within a row, columns are always stored in sorted order by their column name. 
A comparator specifies the data type for the column name, as well as the sort order in which columns are stored within a row.
```

Question- My question is, what it means by Data Type of a Column name?

Till now I learned that a cassandra column ( or a cell for my unserstanding) has three attributes -

1 - Name of the column.

2 - Value of the column.

3 - A Time stamp which represents creation time of the cell.

Question-
I understand the Comaprator requires name of the column to sort the columns in a row, but why the data type of the column name? Data type shoud be always String for a column name.

If I read further on that page, it says

```
Typically, static table names will be strings, and the sort order of columns is not important in that case. For dynamic tables, however, sort order is important.
```

Above statement explains that column names are represented as String for Static tables. As per my understanding, with Dynamic tables we can add new columns which are not defined while defining the table. Now whatever new columns we add with whatever value (with any data type) in newly defined columns, the **data type of the column name** shoud be String, isn't it?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are looking at very very very old documentation. I recommend going straight to 3.0 docs or at least 2.1

Comment: OK . I will refer latest documentation. But still I want to know why data type for column name in old version?

Comment: That question is only relevant in the old thrift world. It does not apply to modern Cassandra at all

Comment: Basically in thrift the cell has two fields and each can have a different comparator, look up Cassandra and thrift for more info but it doesn't apply to the current format

Comment: Thanks. I will keep reading, I will forget about Data Type Of Column Name.